# Problem with Elementary Desktop

Tags: elementary

I'm currently using Ubuntu XFCE4 and I am trying to install elementary-desktop. Except everytime I try to install it, all it comes up with is,

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command `ps aux | grep apt`, which will catch all processes containing the word `apt`.

Remove the process that looks stuck with `kill processID`, where processID is the first set of numbers that occur after the name of the running process.

If that doesn't work, run `kill -9 processID.`

[Source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process/315791#315791)